# Stop loop in Python when a file has been modified

Tags: python

I've a filename `myfile.txt` and I want a simple script that tells me when the file has been modified. I'm using `os.stat(file).st_mtime` to see if it has been modified. If the time has changed, the file has been modified.

How can I use that `os.stat(file).st_mtime` in a while loop to get something like this?

```
while the file hasnt been modified:
     print "File not modified"
print "The file has been modified"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
mtime = os.stat(file).st_mtime
while os.stat(file).st_mtime == mtime:
   print "File not modified"
print "The file has been modified"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m_time = os.stat(file).st_mtime
while os.stat(file).st_mtime == m_time:
   print "File not modified"
   time.sleep(1)
print "The file has been modified"
```

This code checks whether the file has been modified after every second.

Comment: In respect to multitasking the best solution. Improvement is still possible: define a function instead of duplicating os.stat().m_time calls and replace *m_time* by more self-explaining identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value of `st_mtime` before diving into `while` loop and use it for validating the `while` loop:

```
last_st_mtime=os.stat(file).st_mtime
while last_st_mtime==os.stat(file).st_mtime:
     print "File not modified"
print "The file has been modified"
```